# Using variables set at runtime to specify the size of a character array

Tags: c, arrays, string, runtime

I tried to use a variable set at runtime to specify the size of a character array,

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int n;
    printf("ENTER THE NUMBER OF Characters IN THE STRING:\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    char string[n];
    printf("Enter the string:\n");
    scanf("%s",string);
    printf("\nTHE STRING IS:\n");
    printf("%s\n",string);
    return 0;
}
```

I'm not able to understand the following output,

```
ENTER THE NUMBER OF Characters IN THE STRING:
2
Enter the string:
abcdefghijk

THE STRING IS:
abcdefghijk
```

Even after specifying the number of characters in the string as 2, why is the whole of the string that is entered being displayed?

Comment: Because it’s your job to make sure you have enough space, scanf will read as much as it is told to.

Answer (score 1):

Accessing an array index out of bound, invoked [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

C11 Standard:

> **J.2 Undefined behavor**
>
> An array subscript is out of range, even if an object is apparently
>   accessible with the given subscript (as in the lvalue expression
>   `a[1][7]` given the declaration int `a[4][5]`) (6.5.6).
>
> Addition or subtraction of a pointer into, or just beyond, an array
>   object and an integer type produces a result that points just beyond
>   the array object and is used as the operand of a unary * operator that
>   is evaluated (6.5.6).

Answer (score 0):

As you are accessing index which is out of the scope of an array you will get undefined behaviour because of `ArrayIndexOutOfBound`.

In C not checking bounds allows a C program to run faster.

You may prefer

> Dynamic Memory allocation

Answer (score 0):

If you are accessing array elements out of bound, it invokes **undefined behavior**. As `C` doesn't check array boundary condition, compiler won't throw error but it invokes undefined behavior.

*Even after specifying the number of characters in the string as 2, why is the whole of the string that is entered being displayed?* It's a programmer job is to ensure there is enough memory space to store data at runtime and handle such things accordingly.